# In thermodynamics, how does the triple point occur?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition

A triple point is where a matter coexist in its three physical states . But how is it possible and what happens at the microscopic scale?

Comment: What does Wikipedia say about it,   or which part of their article gives you problems.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238097/

Comment: Maybe I dont like the answer of the duplicate ? And it doesn't satisfy me . Should I remove my question?

Comment: The best thing I can recommend is to read through the duplicate and see how your question is different and then repost it, acknowledge  the duplicate but say why your question has a difference. You can delete the question if you like, I think, I am not sure how this system actually works, I think it will be deleted later after another check of it.

Comment: It differs that I said " at the microscopic level" ,I know that at a specific temperature and pressure we obtain the triple point , but I'd like to know what happens at the microscopic scale , regarding the macroscopic parameters( temperature and pressure..) ....

Comment: Then that's exactly what I would put in my revised question, but I would also put in a few lines to show what research or articles if you looked at, even if you have to say you didn't follow them.  It's just that at the quantum level, things can get very detailed, some answers to a "simple" question would fill a book,  so please think of keeping  your questions as focused as possible, even if it takes a few questions to  get there. Best of luck with it.